# How do I transfer a tar.gz file using http post?

Tags: c, http, post, tar, fread

I want to send a tar.gz file using `HTTP post` in C.
However, when reading `tar.gz` file using `fread ()`, it reads only 3 bytes.

```
char *pszfile = null;

FILE *fp = fopen("c:\\test.tar.gz", "rb");

int nSize = 0;

if(fpFile)

{

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

    nSize = ftell(fp);

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    pszfile = (char*)malloc(nSize+1);

    memset(pszfile, 0x00, nSize+1);

    int nReadSize = fread(pszfile, nSize, 1, fp);

    nReadSize = strlen(pszfile);

    printf("pszfile data = %s\n", pszfile);

}
```

pszfile read result = "?"

How do I read a `tar.gz` file using `fread()`?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `strlen` to find binary file size.
Use `nReadSize` to get actual bytes read by `fread`

Comment: You can ignore strlen().